# AJAX call working in Chrome, but not in Safari, Firefox or Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a single page with multiple forms, submitting each of them with an AJAX call to the same PHP controller. In Chrome, when I submit the form, I get a beforeSend message, and then a  success call. In Safari, IE and Firefox, it instead refreshes the page, thus seemingly going right past the ajax call that should keep it from refreshing.

The forms are of this type:

```
<form method="post" class = "multi-form teacher_account_form" id="personal_form" name="personal_form">
    <div class = "form-group">
        <label for="phone">What is your phone number?*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control bfh-phone" data-format="+86 ddd dddd dddd" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?=$this_user[0]['phone']?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-med account_submit" id="personal_submit" name="personal_submit">Update Personal</button>
    </div>                
</form>
```

The JS is like this:

```
var which_button;
$('.account_submit').click(function() {
    which_button = $(this).attr('id');

    // Create empty jQuery objects -
    var $jsOutput = $([]);
    var $jsForm = $([]);

    // url to submit to
    var ajaxURL = "/users/p_teacher_account_work";

    // Assign jQuery selector objects
    switch (which_button) {
        case "work_submit":
            $jsOutput = $('#pay_output');
            $jsForm = $('#pay_form');
            break;
        case "edu_submit":
            $jsOutput = $('#edu_output');
            $jsForm = $('#edu_form');
            break;
        case "image_submit":
            $jsOutput = $('#image_output');
            $jsForm = $('#image_form');
            break;
        case "personal_submit":
            $jsOutput = $('#personal_output');
            $jsForm = $('#personal_form');
            break;
    }

    // Lock and load the ajax request -
    var ajax_options = {
        type: 'post',
        url: ajaxURL,
        beforeSend: function() {
            //Display a loading message while waiting for the ajax call to complete
            $jsOutput.html("Updating...");
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $jsOutput.html(response);
        }
    };
    $jsForm.ajaxForm( ajax_options );


});
```

My php files query the database and send back information to a view which is echoed to the same page that the forms sit on.

Comment: did you try firebug plugin on firefox to see if it shows any error or not?

Comment: firebug: TypeError: setting a property that has only a getter
...bootstrap-formhelpers.min.js
Line 8. I'm only using this plugin on some of the multiple forms on the page, and they all don't work, so I guess it isn't this.

Comment: oh no no no no, lots of things wrong here, where to start!  im surprised that chrome sends this ..., you have a submit button that you click which will always submit with or with out ajax, so you need to function(e) { e.preventDefault;    .... code .... I always return false; just incase the e... doesn't catch.  two your not even sending any of the form data!  etc etc find a tutorial ...

Comment: ok, any to recommend? also, adding in e.preventDefault breaks it in Chrome...

Comment: using e.preventDefault not only stops my ajax call in chrome, but it doesn't stop the page refresh in Firefox

Comment: change the `type="submit"` to `type="button"`

Comment: @Derek ok, now I have prevented submit on firefox, but neither firefox nor Chrome carry out the AJAX request -- should my js now be adjusted?

Comment: you can manually do a `$.post()` but you'll have to grab the form values manually (i'm assuming that the `$.ajaxForm()` method does that automatically?). Also what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: You could use `$.serialize()` on your form element to grab those parameters. See http://api.jquery.com/serialize/.

Comment: I'm not seeing the `ajaxForm()` method anywhere in the jQuery API docs... where is that defined?

Comment: @Derek it's actually a plugin: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: I see.. never used it but briefly looking at their docs all you'd need to do is change `$jsForm.ajaxForm( ajax_options );` to `$jsForm.ajaxSubmit( ajax_options );` (keeping the button type as 'button')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not working because of a boostrap formhelpers plugin country picker dropdown http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/country/#jquery-plugins that wasn't loading correctly in the problematic browsers. For what it's worth, here is the code that wound up working (not including the removal of that nefarious plugin):

```
var which_button;
//$('.account_submit').click(function() {
$('form.teacher_account_form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    which_button = $(this).attr('id');

    // Create empty jQuery objects -
    var $jsOutput = $([]);
    var $jsForm = $([]);

    // url to submit to
    var ajaxURL = "/users/p_teacher_account_work";

    // Assign jQuery selector objects
    switch (which_button) {
        case "pay_form":
            $jsOutput = $('#pay_output');
            $jsForm = $('#pay_form');
            break;
        case "edu_form":
            $jsOutput = $('#edu_output');
            $jsForm = $('#edu_form');
            break;
        case "image_form":
            $jsOutput = $('#image_output');
            $jsForm = $('#image_form');
            break;
        case "personal_form":
            $jsOutput = $('#personal_output');
            $jsForm = $('#personal_form');
            break;
    }

    // empty data object
    var form_data = {};

    // variables for data
    $(this).find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
        var that = $(this),
            name = that.attr('name'),
            value = that.val();

        // load loaded variables into array
        form_data[name] = value;

    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: ajaxURL,
        data: form_data,
        beforeSend: function() {
            //Display a loading message while waiting for the ajax call to complete
            $jsOutput.html("Updating...");
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $jsOutput.html(response);
        }

    });

    return false;


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using type="button" instead of type="submit".

As in:

```
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-med account_submit" id="personal_submit" name="personal_submit">Update Personal</button>
```

It's hacky, but it works in every browser I've tried. The type="submit" means something special to most browsers.

Edit: Wait...are you using Malsup's "jQuery Form Plugin"?

Comment: Yes, I am. Changing it to "button" does stop the page refresh, but doesn't send that AJAX request and also then doesn't send it in Chrome.

Comment: Yes, that "type=button" trick won't work with Malsup's ajaxForm. I can look over the documentation for that plugin if you are intent on using it. Otherwise, I can post a plain vanilla jQuery solution.

Comment: I greet all solutions with equal gratitude.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1.) Turn your button type to `button` a la:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-med account_submit" id="personal_submit" name="personal_submit">Update Personal</button>
```

2.) Change your event handler to call `$jsForm.ajaxSubmit( ajax_options );` instead of `$jsForm.ajaxForm( ajax_options );`

According to their docs, `$jsForm.ajaxForm( ajax_options );` doesn't actually submit the form. The fact that this was working as you expected in Chrome suggests it's doing something weird behind the scenes when submitting forms.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution for a plain, jQuery option:

```
var which_button;

$('.account_submit').click(function() {
    which_button = $(this).attr('id');

    // Create empty jQuery objects -
    var $jsOutput = $([]);
    var $jsForm = $([]);

    // url to submit to
    var ajaxURL = "/users/p_teacher_account_work";

    // Assign jQuery selector objects
    switch (which_button) {
        case "work_submit":
            $jsOutput = $('#pay_output');
            $jsForm = $('#pay_form');
            break;
        case "edu_submit":
            $jsOutput = $('#edu_output');
            $jsForm = $('#edu_form');
            break;
        case "image_submit":
            $jsOutput = $('#image_output');
            $jsForm = $('#image_form');
            break;
        case "personal_submit":
            $jsOutput = $('#personal_output');
            $jsForm = $('#personal_form');
            break;
    }

    // Get the form data
    var formData = $jsForm.serializeArray();

    // Lock and load and fire the ajax request -
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxURL,
        data: formData,
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false, // this will save you a bunch of IE headaches
        beforeSend: function() {
            //Display a loading message while waiting for the ajax call to complete
            $jsOutput.html("Updating...");
        },
        error: function(jqHXR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Sorry, something went wrong.\nDetails: " + textStatus + ". " + errorThrown);
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $jsOutput.html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Now, you can make the button type="button" or even replace it with an element with no default onclick event action such as a span.

Comment: Let me know if you get any errors. You may need to adjust the contentType and dataType to meet your needs.

Comment: it never gets past the beforeSend, "updating..."

Comment: Okay. Could I get some console error message information? We may need to change the dataType.

You can view the Chrome console by right-clicking anywhere on the page, then click "inspect element". A little window should open below. Click on the "Console" tab. Now, hit your ajax button. Any JavaScript errors should show up here. Please post them.

Also, click on the Network tab. This will show the status of your AJAX requests. You can inspect the status of each AJAX request using this tab.

I'll update my example to include some error logging.

Comment: hey man, it was this stupid form element not being supported in all those browsers where it didn't work. [form-helper country picker](http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/country/#jquery-plugins) . It was destroying the entire ajax request ... sorry for the goose chase

Comment: No problem. Glad you found the solution. :)